# Using Abflug vs Abfahrt

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, meaning

What's the exact difference and how should those words be used?

P.S.: Is it when we talk about air travel and land travel?

Comment: Flug = flight / Fahrt = drive --> Abflug = takeoff / Abfahrt = yeah.. leaving a place (departure has both meaning, so it doesn't fit at all)

Comment: I've heard _Abflug_ in the sense of departure in colloquial use. _Aufbruch_ would be a way to express the same meaning in standard language.

Comment: @AnsgarEsztermann Do you mean *Mach' 'nen Abflug*? I don't think that the question is about such a thing.

Comment: @Em1 No, I was thinking of a one-word sentence, _Abflug!_, in the sense of _We shall leave immediately, everyone who wants to join us should do so now_

Comment: @Em1: In this case it is used metaphorical, as other metaphors too.

Comment: If you want a term which describes both of them (like departure), you could say "Abreise", but the concrete form should always be preferred.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Abflug (masc.) is the departure of a means of transport that can fly (e.g. an airplane). Abfahrt (fem.) of those that can be driven on the ground (e.g. a car). So, when talking about air travel, use the former, when talking about land travel, the latter. As a neutral word for all kind of travels you could use "Abreise" (fem.).

Answer (score 5):

The literal meaning has been described by AGuyCalledGerald already...

I'd like to add the figure of speech meanings, as far as I know them:

**Abflug** can be a general departure in "slang"

> Ich mach' einen Abflug.

basically means that I will leave that bar, party or BBQ You can also use it tell people to go away.

> Mach 'nen Abflug.

**Abfahrt** is used to describe an intense part of a DJ Set or Song... for example a loooong trance break and then the snare roll and then finally the base kicks in; that would be a reason to scream "Abfaaaaahrt"

For completion **Abfahrt** is also the correct word in a ski resort both for the downhill track and the action of riding it down. This meaning uses *ab* as down rather than *of*

Comment: Your answer is completely correct and, though, your answer is completely off-topic.

Comment: As a non-German learning the language, it's fascinating to learn of these kinds of colloquial usages of words, even if it's not the "correct" usage of the word in the purely grammatical sense.